# UITableView addSubview and table lines

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to add a custom view to an UITableView created with code from an UITableViewController. This view is a HUD window with a message ([MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD))

So I have a method reload() called from the overridden initWithStyle() method and from the refresh button of the table:

```
- (void) reload {
    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.tableView];
    [self.view addSubview:HUD];
    HUD.delegate = self;
    HUD.labelText = @"Downloading";
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(reloadWithHUD) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
}
```

The first time, the HUD appears behind the table lines. Once loaded, when I press reload button, the view shows as expected. The initWithStyle() method (with some code removed for clarity) is:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
        self.title = NSLocalizedString...

        UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle ... action:@selector(reload)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
        [button autorelease];
        [self reload];      
    }

    return self;
}
```

I've tried changing the HUD view with a simple UILabel, with the same result.
I also changed the code to call reload() from viewDidLoad(), but doesn't work either. How can I resolve this issue? Thank you very much.

**EDIT :** to clarify this, here is a possible solution to this problem. Many thanks to Bill Brasky for his help:

```
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:HUD];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I'm doing in my app with an almost identical application.

You need to add it to the main view WINDOW, not the tableView.

```
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view.window];
[self.view.window addSubView:HUD];
```

Comment: Thank you Bill, I've tried it also but I got the same result.

Comment: I had issues with my use of MBProgressHUD in the new beta. Are you by chance using the new beta and/or an older version of MBProgressHUD? I know there were some updates on git to help things out. Just checking in case it isn't related to your code, but the progress view itself.

Comment: I looked at my code, see my edits in my answer and let me know.

Comment: Thank you again, Bill. I've updated to the latest git version. I've tried your code, but I get an exception because self.view.window appears to be nil. But with your help, I've found the solution, using the following code:  `HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];` `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:HUD];`

Comment: Great! Those lines worked in one of my views, but not in all. I'll take a look at your changes and see if that helps me in my other views.

Comment: I used your method of adding the HUD to my view and resolved all of my errant crashes in the HUD. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

My project is based on IOS 7
This helps me

`[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];`